# Internal Storage calculation wrong

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow

[image]

The calculation does not really add up. Previosly more storage was occupied by Spotify although the downloaded music is saved to the external SD card. How can I get Android to recognize the correct free space?

Motorola G 2015

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the phone just needs a quick restart. Try that and if it doesn't work then let me know.

Comment: I ended up using a custom ROM as even a factory reset didn't solve the problem. Still the Spotify issue exists. I assume there are some hidden files I didn't discover yet.

Comment: @idkfa Hmm. Did you try a FULL wipe of the internal storage too? It's a little extreme but it's all I can think of.